# What does the notation $\epsilon(f(x))s$ mean?

Tags: differential-topology

I am very, very confused with the notion $\epsilon(f(x))s$.

To my understanding, $s$ is a map sends to $F(x,s)$, and $\epsilon$ is the distance function given a point $f(x)$. So what does $\epsilon(f(x))s$ means, when we just put them together? Multiplication of two functions?

> **Corollary.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a smooth map, $Y$ being boundaryless.
>   Then there is an open ball $S$ in some Euclidean space and a smooth map $F\colon X\times S\to Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$, and for any fixed $x\in X$ the map $s\mapsto F(x,s)$ is a submersion $S\to Y$. In particular, both $F$ and $\partial F$ are submersions.
>
> *Proof.* Let $S$ be the unit ball in $\mathbf R^M$, the ambient Euclidean space of $Y$, and define
>   $$F(x,s)=\pi[f(x)+\epsilon(f(x))s].$$
>   Since $\pi\colon Y^\epsilon\to Y$ restricts to the identity on $Y$, $F(x,0) = f(x)$.
>   For fixed $x$, 
>   $$s\mapsto f(x)+\epsilon(f(x))s.$$

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You may need to read back further in the text to find out.

Comment: Thank you @dfeuer. From the previous, $S$ is an open ball and $s$ is an element in it. But I couldn't get through from this...

Comment: $s$ doesn't look like a map to me, but I don't know this sort of math.

Comment: @dfeuer I am completely astonished by how did you Mathjaxified it....?!!!

Comment: I've changed a $f$ into an $F$ where it was clearly a typo or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are living in the ambient Euclidean space of $Y$, say $E=\mathbb R^M$, points may be added componentwise like vectors, and multiplied by scalars similarly. Then since $f(x)\in Y\subset E$, and $s\in S\subset E$, and $\epsilon(f(x))\in \mathbb R$, it makes perfect sense to compute the scalar product of the second with the third, and then add the first. The result is some point in the ambient space $E$. This is then projected back into $Y$ using $\pi$.

Comment: Oh, that clears so much!! Thanks Sharkos!!